# How to Change Django Default Page to your Design?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I uploaded my site to the live server, but still, I am seeing Django default page, I updated my `urls.py` file, but still, it's not working. and it's showing me this output. Please let me know where I am Mistaking.

```
I am trying to access this mydomain.com/dashboard

 Using the URLconf defined in yoursite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 admin/
The current path, dashboard, didn't match any of these.
```

here is my urls.py file...

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
url('', include('frontpanel.urls')),
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And here is my views.py file...

```
def index(request):
category = Category.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
return render(request, "base.html", {'category':category})
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Django are you using? 
Try changing `url` to `re_path` (remember to import it first). I think `url` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

After Analyzing the question u never mentioned ur app urls.py you only mentioned project urls.py . As u have `url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),` in ur project urls.py, there must be a file in your app also named urls.py which handles urls having prefix `/dashboard/` , by default django doesnt make that file you need to manually make it add ur function names to redirect . For example this is my main urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('display_report/', include("display_report.urls"))
]
```

then u have to make a file named urls.py in ur app also to handle the requests and redirect the the approaite functions , in my `display_report` app i made a urls.py that looks like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from display_report import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [path('', views.index)]
```

And then it will redirect to function named index in ur views.py file inside ur app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
# from .models import Employee, Tasks, Report, Fileupload, Fileuploadnext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request."index.html")
```

Here my ur will be `mydomain.com/display_report` and my index.html file will be inside the template folder